# Getting Twitter Follower and Friends Network for multiple users in R

Tags: r, twitter, igraph

Dear all I am new to R and I need your help,

I have a list of usernames for which I need to retrieve all followers and friends and create an edge list and store it in a CSV.file for further analysis. Problem: The list of usernames I have compiled is quite large, I need to iterate over the vector of users and aggregate each user's results into one file.
 I can do this one by one, but it' obviously nicer to do this automatically. Here's the code I used to create an edgelist for ONE twitter user. As I explained I intend to do the same, but for a large number of twitter usernames.
Assuming that a connection with the Twitter API has been established I use the following packages:

```
library(twitteR)
library(foreign)
library(xlsx)
library(base64enc)
library(rJava)
library(devtools)
library(RCurl)
library(igraph)
```

Then I get the user friends:

```
start <- getUser("@camharvey")
friends_object <- lookupUsers(start$getFriendIDs())
friends_object
friendsCount(start)
```

## get the user followers

```
followers_object <- lookupUsers(start$getFollowerIDs())
followers_object
followersCount(start)
```

## Create a list from both objects

```
friends <- sapply(friends_object[1:117],name)
followers <- sapply(followers_object[1:1033],name)
```

## Merge both lists into a data frame to create an edge file from followers and friends

```
relations <- merge(data.frame(User='@camharvey',followers=friends), data.frame(User=followers, followers='@camharvey'), all=TRUE)
```

How can I do the same for multiple usernames?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a for loop and loop over the list of usernames to populate a list. Then turn this list into an edgelist. This will take some time, since you say you have a large number of users and the list of friends and followers can be quite large. (In particular, the lines `lookupUsers(start$getFriendIDs())` and `followers_object <- lookupUsers(start$getFollowerIDs())` take quite some time, not sure if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this...)

```
users <- c("@camharvey",etc.) #List of usernames
userrelations <- list() #Create an empty list to populate

for (i in 1:length(users)){
  start <- getUser(users[i])
  friends_object <- lookupUsers(start$getFriendIDs())
  followers_object <- lookupUsers(start$getFollowerIDs())
  friends <- sapply(1:length(friends_object), 
                    function(x) name(friends_object[[x]]))
  followers <- sapply(1:length(followers_object), 
                      function(x) name(followers_object[[x]]))
  userrelations[[i]] <- merge(data.frame(User=users[i],followers=friends),
                              data.frame(User=followers, followers=users[i]), 
                              all=TRUE)
}
```

This populates a list of each user's network of friends and followers. Next, combine all the elements of the list into a data frame and write to csv:

```
user_el <- do.call("rbind",userrelations)
write.csv(user_el, "filename.csv", row.names = F)
```

I tried this with only three users and it took some time. On my computer, the run time looks like this:

```
   user  system elapsed 
175.544   3.356 317.304
```

FYI, `start$getFollowerIDs()` is *much* faster than `lookupUsers(start$getFollowerIDs())`, so it you can use ID numbers rather than names, it will go much faster.

Comment: Dear Paqmo, thanks a lot for your reply. It works wonderfully. Cheers